# How do I write all of these rows into a CSV file for a given range?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, web-scraping

The purpose of the below code is the webscrape the oxford english dictionary for words that were "invented" in each year within a range of years. This all works as intended.

```
import csv
import os
import re
import requests
import urllib2

year_start= 1550
year_end = 1552
subject_search = ['Law']

for year in range(year_start, year_end +1):
    path = '/Applications/Python 3.5/Economic'
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    header = {'User-Agent':user_agent}

    resultPath = os.path.join(path, 'OED_table.csv')
    htmlPath = os.path.join(path, 'OED.html')
    request = urllib2.Request('http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&dateFilter='+ str(year)+ '&nearDistance=1&ordered=false&page=1&pageSize=100&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&subjectClass='+ str(subject_search)+ '&type=dictionarysearch', None, header)
    page = opener.open(request)

    with open(resultPath, 'wb') as outputw, open(htmlPath, 'w') as outputh:
        urlpage = page.read()
        outputh.write(urlpage)

        new_words = re.findall(r'<span class=\"hwSect\"><span class=\"hw\">(.*?)</span>', urlpage)
        print new_words
        csv_writer = csv.writer(outputw)
        if csv_writer.writerow([year] + new_words):
            csv_writer.writerow([year, word])
```

However, when I actually run the code, the only portion that gets written to the csv file is the very last year that I call. So, my csv file ends up looking like a one row like this:

1552, word1, word2, word3, etc....

I basically want to have a separate row for each year in the range of years. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting in the loop and every time you run the code, open it once outside the loops and *append* to the file opening with `a` instead of `w` so each run of the code will add to the existing data not overwrite.:

```
with open("/Applications/Python 3.5/Economic/OED_table.csv", 'a') as outputw, open("/Applications/Python 3.5/Economic/OED.html", 'a') as outputh:     
    for year in range(year_start, year_end +1):
       .....................
```